# If I refresh a page will the controller be invoked at all in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a products website and have a model for `Product` and a `ProductController`. There's an `index.html` to display the list of products.

If I refresh the index page on the browser, it's clear that the view will be called again - but will that invoke the controller too?

Comment: reloading page is to send fresh request and request is always entertained by server side controller. What do you expect/think it could do else?

Comment: I suggest you to read `MVC in rails` and how its flow goes

Comment: Your answer is in your question, you said `view is called again` but who is calling view? action inside controller indeed!

Comment: Thanks fo the replies. If I need to place apiece of code which should be executed EVERYTIME the page/view is refreshed, which method should I place it inside? My controller has various methods for CRUD operations like `create`, `update`, `destroy`, `index`. Should I place my code inside `index` method? or should I place it in `init` method instead?

Comment: Use `before_action` to put your code inside one method and call it before each action in that controller

Comment: If you need to execute "piece of code" before every action in all controllers, place it in before_action in ApplicationController

Comment: @Vasilisa need might be for one controller and not for all controllers, so use of  `ApplicationController` before_action is not needed in such a case

Comment: @Vasilisa, @ray -  I added my "piece of code" inside the `index` method of my controller and that seems to work perfectly every time I refresh my page. Would that be "an" answer to this question? or am I missing some scenario when this might not work?

Comment: Yes, it will work on every refresh of `index` page. Do you need it on any other page?

Comment: No - I need this only on one page.